La définition de « phanotron » dans le CNRTL est-elle erronée ?
La définition de phanotron sur le site web du Centre National de Ressources Textuelles et Lexicales (CNRTL) se lit comme suit : « Diode de redressement thermoélectronique (à filament chaud) qui utilise une décharge à arc en vapeur de mercure ou dans un gaz inerte, habituellement le zénon »
Je ne connais pas le zénon comme gaz inerte, mais je connais le xénon ; je n'ai pas trouvé de référence pour zénon comme gaz inerte.
Ma question est donc : s'agit-il d'une erreur dans le CNRTL ?

Oui, il ne peut s'agir que d'une coquille probablement due à la proximité avec le nom du philosophe grec Zénon.
Elle n'est cependant pas le fait du CNRTL qui n'est ici qu'un portail vers des ressources variées.
Il s'agit soit d'une erreur du TLFi (Trésor de la langue française informatisé), soit d'une erreur de reconnaissance de caractère lors de la numérisation de cet ouvrage, soit, moins vraisemblablement, d'une erreur de la source citée (Encyclopédie Science et Techniques).
Les lettres x et z minuscules peuvent parfois être confondues :

